# Post json data stored in variable using curl

Tags: php, json, curl, post

Sending POST request data stored in a variable using curl, sends $variable instead json data.

```
P=`/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data-urlencode $data http://127.0.0.1/abc.php`
```

Trying to send POST request to php, but it receives $data instead json data`{"abc":"11","xyz":"20"}`.

Had try with '$data', "$data", \'$data\' and \"$data\", where $data = {"abc":"11","xyz":"20"}

Please give an example that works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$variables` variables are only expanded if they are in a DOUBLE QUOTED String literal. You are using backticks

Comment: 'P=`/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/curl --data-urlencode  request=$O http://127.0.0.1/abc.php`', this works fine with backticks, but there is value for json included space truncate the request. E.g. "val":"value string". So I tried to go for post request.

Answer (score 0):

```
P=`/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "$O" http://127.0.0.1/abc.php` solves issue.
```

If you add single quote it won't expand variable, so it requires to add double quote.

I suggest all time reload page or script, as I have seen if you not reload, it work with your last change instead new one.